# Dr. Java: Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[] when running program

Tags: user-interface, drjava

I am taking my second Java class ever, and was told by my professor to use Dr. Java. We have started learning GUI, and he has given us some sample code as examples:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.collections.*;


public class HelloWorldMain extends Application{
 public void start(Stage primaryStage){
  FlowPane pane = new FlowPane();

  // put all controls on 'pane'
  Label lblHello = new Label("Hello");
  pane.getChildren().add(lblHello);

  Button btnHello = new Button("Hello World");
  pane.getChildren().add(btnHello);

  TextField txtHello = new TextField("Hello");
  pane.getChildren().add(txtHello);

  PasswordField pass = new PasswordField();
  pane.getChildren().add(pass);

  CheckBox cbHello = new CheckBox("Hello");
  pane.getChildren().add(cbHello);

  RadioButton rbMale= new RadioButton("Male");
  RadioButton rbFemale = new RadioButton("Female");
      pane.getChildren().add(rbMale);
      pane.getChildren().add(rbFemale);

  ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
  rbMale.setToggleGroup(group);
  rbFemale.setToggleGroup(group);

  ChoiceBox cbColors = new ChoiceBox();
  cbColors.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Red", "Green", "Blue"));

  pane.getChildren().add(cbColors);


  Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 200);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.show();
 }
}
```

However, when I try to run this in Java, I get the following error:
Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[].

Professor is not able to help me, and I don't see an answer to this exact question. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think Javafx programs necessarily need a main. I'm pretty sure it's automatically added when the program is compiled. Dr. Java probably isn't smart enough to know that. In every other case, you need to explicitly supply a `main` method.

Comment: ["The main() method is not required for JavaFX applications when the JAR file for the application is created with the JavaFX Packager tool, which embeds the JavaFX Launcher in the JAR file"](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm). If you guys are using said packaging tool, `main` isn't required.

Comment: Is there a better program to use (like NetBeans) or a specific way to modify the code in Dr. Java?

Comment: Honestly, I've never used Dr. Java (I'm assuming it's a linter?), and haven't used Netbeans for years. I couldn't tell you unfortunately. It depends on what advice you want it to give. IntelliJ (which I've used for years) gives many good hints and helps catch many errors for you. It's free too. You'll need to make sure your instructor isn't expecting you to use a certain IDE though.

Comment: I don't think that my professor will know what I am using, as for assignments we are only required to submit the .java file. I will take your suggestion and use IntelliJ. Thank you!

Comment: Note though that IntelliJ is a beast. It's very productive to use, but it itself has a learning curve. I wouldn't switch in the middle of a course unless you're really feeling hindered (unless you aren't already invested in NetBeans).